# HTML doesn't recognize css file and doesn't import it

Tags: html, css, intellij-idea, bootstrap-4

No idea why I can't seem to be able to import a styles.css file into a standard HTML page.
The code compiles, but my page doesn't receive any changes whatsoever from the css file.

src/main/resources/templates/page.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="card text-center">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="new-header">New header</h4>
            <a class="btn btn-primary new-button">New button</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

src/main/resources/static/css/styles.css

```
.new-button{
    float:right;
}

.new-header{
    float: left;
}
```

I've tried switching the href directory link to several others, such as :

/css/styles.css (the one used by a similar project);

/static/css/styles.css (the IDE considers this to be the best one)

Comment: Can you try “../static/css/styles.css”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking in the wrong directory. Change the `href` to

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/styles.css"/>
```

the double dot at the start are necessary:
`../static/css/styles.css`